# Excel Formatting Data Validation Input

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a workbook with a list of sheets all in a date format (5-18-20, 5-19-20).  I have a VBA function that will collect this list and put it in a comma-separated string.  But whenever I try to set a cell's data validation to a hard-coded comma-separated list, it formats the date values.

Example: If I set the data validation list to only "5-18-20" it becomes "5/18/2020"

How can I prevent this?  Setting the cells formatting to "text" does not prevent this.

Here is the image that I type in to the data validation dialog.

[image: My input]

Here is what Excel changes it to:

[image: Excels changes]

Comment: Where is the undesired date format? In the dropdown list or in the cell after you've selected from the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

Format the cell that has the data validation with the desired date format.

The date values in the data validation drop-down will appear in the format that your computer settings uses as the default in the regional settings.

Comment: The issue with that is I'm using the INDIRECT function to reference the sheets, and if it's not set as just text it pulls the number value of the date.

So 5-18 becomes 43969.0

Comment: What? You said you use VBA to pull together a string. Please describe all the moving elements in your scenario. Edit your question and describe the whole picture, not just parts of it.

Comment: Alright, I've updated my original post.  I just need the comma separated list of dates in the data validation source field to not change from my original input.